# Blazor Server BaseUri wrong for app service redirected by azure frontdoor

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c, blazor-server-side, azure-front-door

Situation:

- Blazor Server running in an app service
- Azure AD B2C used for authentication
- Azure Frontdoor is used to map custom domain to app service and provide WAF policies etc

Problem:

- Authentication not working because wrong redirect url is being constructed https://myapp.azurewebsites.net instead of https://myapp.mydomain.com
- Various other features are not working because NavigationManager.BaseUri is also pointing to the wrong url instead of my own domain

How do I get the app service behind the Azure frontdoor to work.

Comment: Try to use NavigationManager.Uri or NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("") to get the absolute URL with the custom domain.

Comment: I do that and then I get the https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/ url instead of the custom domain url

Comment: [Does the answer useful to you ?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1162808/afd-custom-domain-redirects-to-the-origin-host-nam)

Comment: I also find the github issue you raised, you also can check the solution microsoft provided.